# What is the best way to represent arbitrarily big numbers in c?

Tags: c, biginteger

I'm working on a project that requires me to work with numbers larger than the largest numerical datatype in c. I was thinking of using structs with bit fields to represent this, but it's already smelling bad. Anyone got any tips? (Not looking for a library, more of a thought process to go behind doing something like this.)

Comment: I disagree that this is an exact duplicate of the reference. I'm not looking for a library (should have specified that), but the best practice of large numerical data. In this case it is on Linux, but this should be platform agnostic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest to first check out the GNU MP Bignum library.

If licensing is a problem you have to roll your own. My first choice for the data-type would be a simple array of unsigned chars along with some extra data to denote how large that array is.

Something like this:

```
typedef struct 
{
  unsigned char * NumberData;
  size_t          AllocatedSize;
} MyBigNum;
```

Should be sufficient.

Answer (score 9):

[The GNU MP Bignum Library](http://gmplib.org/) would be my first choice.