# How to divide big numbers using string

Tags: c, string, math, biginteger

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best way to represent arbitrarily big numbers in c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619764/what-is-the-best-way-to-represent-arbitrarily-big-numbers-in-c)
>   [Are there any solid large integer implementations in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191002/are-there-any-solid-large-integer-implementations-in-c)

I need to divide two int big numbers and want only the integer result (not remainder)
like 987654321987654321 / 98765432198
where the numbers cannot be stored in long long int.
i think i  should use string but i have got no idea where to start.
by the way i am using c.please help !!!

Answer (score 4):

Like [on paper](http://www.klever.net/spilikin/arithmetikin/divide)? But you may want to look at [gmp](http://gmplib.org/) if it's for any practical purpose, instead.

Answer (score 1):

As Michael Krelin said, the best option for serious use is a tried and tested, seriously-tuned-by-someone-else bignum package like GMP. It is, however, fun and instructive to implement your own. You would typically store the numbers as arrays of 'digits' and, as a first step implement addition, subtraction, multiplication and division using the on-paper algorithms you learnt in school. As long as you enjoy fiddling with it, you'd then implement more functionality and optimise the algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

For the kind of numbers you mention, you can use doubles

```
int q = 987654321987654321.0 / 98765432198.0
```