# The formula P(n) = (n!)(6^n) in C produces a large value

Tags: c, factorial, approximate

I'm trying to represent the following mathematical expression in C:

P(n) = (n!)(6^n)

The program should compute the answer to expression when `n` = 156. I have attempted to create the program in C and it fails to produce an answer. The answer is approximately 10^397. The program utilises 2 logarithmic identities. It also utilises Stirling's approximation to calculate the large factorial.

How can I make it produce the correct answer and do you have any suggestions as to how I could improve the code? (I'm fairly new to programming):

```
#include <math.h>
typedef unsigned int uint;

int main()
{
uint n=156;                               // Declare variables
double F,pi=3.14159265359,L,e=exp(1),P;
F = sqrt(2*pi*n) * pow((n/e),n);          // Stirling's Approximation Formula
L = log(F) + n*log(6);                    // Transform P(n) using logarithms - log(xy) = log(x) + log(y) and log(y^n) = n*log(y)
P = pow(e,L);                             // Transform the resultant logarithm back to a normal numbers
}
```

Thank you! :)

Comment: Hey I saw this question on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ (in Python instead of C, which is why it's not likely to work out for you as easily as it worked there).

Comment: 10^397 is not representable as a double. See DBL_MAX.

Comment: Yep, that was posted by me. I'm now trying to represent the same program but in C. I think there's an issue with the precision I am using though.I posted it on Overflow instead of Code review as the program needs fixing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I would like to add 2 arbitrarily sized integers in C++. How can I go about doing this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2926219/i-would-like-to-add-2-arbitrarily-sized-integers-in-c-how-can-i-go-about-doin)

Comment: Changing your code to use `long double` I get 1.83969e+397 with gcc...

Comment: `long double` *may or may not*` be able to represent the result. On some systems, `long double` is substantially larger in range and precision than `double`. On others, it's the same (though it's still a distinct type).

Answer (score 4):

Neither integer nor floating point variables in most C implementations can support numbers of that magnitude. Typical 64-bit doubles go up to something like 10<sup>308</sup> with substantial loss of precision at that magnitude.

You'll need what's called a 'bignum library' to compute this, which is not part of standard C.

Comment: Is there any way whatsoever to represent 10^397 using standard C?

Comment: @thelastpanda: Not with any native types; you'll either have to use a third-party bignum library, or roll your own arbitrary precision code.

Comment: Does it help that P is only meant to be an approximation? So...the loss of precision is acceptable.

Comment: How extensive would the arbitrary precision code be?

Comment: You might check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Multiple_Precision_Arithmetic_Library

Comment: Would this work for my problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/619764/what-is-the-best-way-to-represent-arbitrarily-big-numbers-in-c

Comment: Can I see your code Fred as 1.83969e+397 is the correct answer.

Comment: The type `long double` *on some systems* had a wider range than `double`. On my system, `LDBL_MAX` is about `1.189731e+4932`. I think Windows compilers typically give `long double` the same representation and range as `double` (which is perfectly legal as far as the C standard is concerned).

Answer (score 1):

One idea is to use the `long double` type. Its precision isn't guaranteed, so it may or may not be big enough for your needs, depending on what compiler you're using.

Replace `double` with `long double`. Add an 'l' (lower case L) suffix to all math functions (`expl`, `logl`, `powl`, `sqrtl`). Compile with C99 enabled, since the `long double` math functions are provided in C99. It worked for me using GCC 4.8.1.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
typedef unsigned int uint;

int main()
{
    uint n=156;                               // Declare variables
    long double F,pi=3.14159265359,L,e=expl(1),P;
    F = sqrtl(2*pi*n) * powl((n/e),n);          // Stirling's Approximation Formula
    L = logl(F) + n*logl(6);                    // Transform P(n) using logarithms - log(xy) = log(x) + log(y) and log(y^n) = n*log(y)
    P = powl(e,L);                             // Transform the resultant logarithm back to a normal numbers
    printf("%Lg\n", P);
}
```

I get `1.83969e+397`.

Comment: I get approximately -4.68e+66. :(

Comment: Ouch. What compiler are you using? You may have to tweak your compile options.

Comment: Try adding an `#include <float.h>` and `printf("%d\n", LDBL_MAX_10_EXP);`. That will show you the maximum base-10 exponent `long double` can represent. You might be out of luck with that compiler.

Comment: Interesting. That should be big enough. Did you miss any of the math functions?

Comment: Posted what I did below:

Comment: Please don't post that as an answer. Looks like you got them all. What specifier did you use for `printf`?

Comment: I meant to print the `long double` result. You need an 'L' prefix, like `"%Lf"` or `"%Lg"`.

Comment: I tried %Ld, %Lf and %Lg. None of them printed the correct answer.

Comment: There seems to be a common misconception that `long double` was introduced by C99 ((I've even seen it in published books). In fact, the `long double` type was introduced by the ANSI C standard in 1989. The `<math.h>` functions with names ending in `l` that operate on `long double` *were* introduced by C99. (I know you said "provided by", not "introduced by".)

Comment: @KeithThompson: You're correct. C99 apparently increased support for `long double`, but it existed in C89. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_double#History Do you recommend any rewording of my answer to avoid perpetuating the myth?

Comment: @FredLarson: You could just drop the phrase "provided in C99", and perhaps add something to say that the `*l()` library functions were added by C99.

Answer (score 0):

Loosely speaking, in C a double is represented as a base number raised to a power.  As already mentioned, the maximum is roughly 1E308, but as you get to larger and larger numbers (or smaller and smaller), you lose precision because the base number has a finite number of digits and cannot always be accurately represented in this way.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format for more information

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. The problem is that the mathematical result is outside the range of type `double`, not that there's insufficient precision.

Comment: Well, yes.  That answer was already given, but I think that if someone is going to be working with large numbers like this, it's important to understand, at least on some level, how it works.

Comment: Then it would be more appropriate as a comment.

Comment: I would have, but it requires 50 reputation to comment on other people's answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <math.h>
#include <float.h>
typedef unsigned int uint;

int main()
{
uint n=156;                               // Declare variables
long double F,pi=3.14159265359,L,e=expl(1),P;
F = sqrtl(2*pi*n) * powl((n/e),n);          // Stirling's Approximation Formula
L = logl(F) + n*logl(6);                    // Transform P(n) using logarithms - log(xy) = log(x) + log(y) and log(y^n) = n*log(y)
P = powl(e,L);                             // Transform the resultant logarithm back to a normal numbers
printf("%d\n", LDBL_MAX_10_EXP);
}
```